# Residual errors from the klaR. Stepwise LDA

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `klaR` package to do a stepwise analysis on spectral data. I have 400 (spectra readings) variables and about 40 factors (plants). Running the following code I get the subsequent error:

```
gw<- greedy.wilks(plant ~ ., data = logged, niveau = 0.1)
Error in summary.manova(e2, test = "Wilks") : residuals have rank 53 < 54
```

I thought I was getting this error because the varaible data is highly correlated, hence I tried log-transforming. I ran the same code but this time including `qr = FALSE`. Got the same error. I hve searched for solutions and reasons for this error and most point towards high correlations or differences in variable and factor numbers. I would like to keep all the variables, beacause I am using this procedure for feature selection, therefore deleting the highly correlated data isn't really an option, unless I have to.

Is there a valid way around this problem?

Data looks like this:

`

```
 dput(str(logged))
   'data.frame':   1020 obs. of  402 variables:
    $ plant: Factor w/ 5 levels "ADPA","ALAL",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
    $ R400 : num  0.147 0.144 0.145 0.141 0.129 ...
    $ R405 : num  0.147 0.144 0.145 0.143 0.132 ...
    $ R410 : num  0.142 0.138 0.141 0.139 0.129 ...
    $ R415 : num  0.143 0.141 0.144 0.141 0.133 ...
    $ R420 : num  0.142 0.141 0.143 0.142 0.133 ...
    $ R425 : num  0.144 0.145 0.147 0.145 0.137 ...
    $ R430 : num  0.147 0.147 0.149 0.147 0.14 ...
    $ R435 : num  0.148 0.147 0.15 0.148 0.142 ...
 $ R440 : num  0.15 0.149 0.152 0.15 0.143 ...
 $ R445 : num  0.152 0.152 0.155 0.153 0.147 ...
 $ R450 : num  0.155 0.154 0.156 0.154 0.149 ...
 $ R455 : num  0.155 0.155 0.156 0.155 0.15 ...
 $ R460 : num  0.156 0.155 0.157 0.155 0.151 ...
 $ R465 : num  0.155 0.155 0.156 0.154 0.151 ...
 $ R470 : num  0.156 0.155 0.157 0.155 0.152 ...
 $ R475 : num  0.155 0.155 0.156 0.155 0.152 ...
 $ R480 : num  0.155 0.155 0.157 0.155 0.152 ...
 $ R485 : num  0.157 0.156 0.157 0.156 0.153 ...
 $ R490 : num  0.159 0.158 0.159 0.158 0.156 ...
 $ R495 : num  0.162 0.162 0.162 0.161 0.16 ...
 $ R500 : num  0.17 0.169 0.169 0.168 0.168 ...
 $ R505 : num  0.182 0.18 0.179 0.179 0.182 ...
 $ R510 : num  0.203 0.201 0.197 0.199 0.206 ...
 $ R515 : num  0.237 0.233 0.225 0.23 0.245 ...
 $ R520 : num  0.281 0.274 0.261 0.27 0.296 ...
 $ R525 : num  0.325 0.314 0.297 0.311 0.35 ...
 $ R530 : num  0.36 0.345 0.324 0.343 0.394 ...
 $ R535 : num  0.383 0.365 0.34 0.363 0.425 ...
 $ R540 : num  0.396 0.376 0.349 0.375 0.445 ...
 $ R545 : num  0.407 0.384 0.356 0.384 0.461 ...
 $ R550 : num  0.412 0.389 0.359 0.389 0.47 ...
 $ R555 : num  0.404 0.381 0.351 0.381 0.464 ...
 $ R560 : num  0.383 0.361 0.333 0.362 0.443 ...
 $ R565 : num  0.355 0.334 0.308 0.336 0.414 ...
 $ R570 : num  0.323 0.304 0.281 0.306 0.378 ...
 $ R575 : num  0.295 0.279 0.259 0.282 0.347 ...
 $ R580 : num  0.275 0.261 0.244 0.265 0.324 ...
 $ R585 : num  0.262 0.248 0.233 0.252 0.308 ...
 $ R590 : num  0.253 0.24 0.226 0.244 0.299 ...
 $ R595 : num  0.248 0.235 0.222 0.24 0.293 ...
 $ R600 : num  0.242 0.23 0.217 0.234 0.285 ...
 $ R605 : num  0.232 0.221 0.21 0.225 0.272 ...
 $ R610 : num  0.219 0.209 0.2 0.214 0.255 ...
 $ R615 : num  0.207 0.199 0.191 0.204 0.239 ...
 $ R620 : num  0.199 0.192 0.186 0.197 0.229 ...
 $ R625 : num  0.196 0.189 0.183 0.194 0.225 ...
 $ R630 : num  0.194 0.187 0.182 0.192 0.223 ...
 $ R635 : num  0.191 0.184 0.179 0.189 0.218 ...
 $ R640 : num  0.184 0.177 0.173 0.181 0.208 ...
 $ R645 : num  0.175 0.169 0.167 0.173 0.195 ...
 $ R650 : num  0.167 0.163 0.162 0.166 0.183 ...
 $ R655 : num  0.161 0.158 0.158 0.161 0.173 ...
 $ R660 : num  0.153 0.152 0.154 0.155 0.161 ...
 $ R665 : num  0.148 0.148 0.152 0.151 0.153 ...
 $ R670 : num  0.147 0.148 0.152 0.15 0.151 ...
 $ R675 : num  0.149 0.15 0.156 0.152 0.152 ...
 $ R680 : num  0.154 0.156 0.162 0.157 0.158 ...
 $ R685 : num  0.165 0.166 0.172 0.168 0.174 ...
 $ R690 : num  0.196 0.193 0.195 0.199 0.221 ...
 $ R695 : num  0.277 0.267 0.258 0.277 0.329 ...
 $ R700 : num  0.42 0.401 0.378 0.415 0.501 ...
 $ R705 : num  0.6 0.576 0.539 0.59 0.702 ...
 $ R710 : num  0.791 0.764 0.719 0.778 0.901 ...
 $ R715 : num  0.984 0.956 0.909 0.968 1.088 ...
 $ R720 : num  1.17 1.14 1.1 1.15 1.26 ...
 $ R725 : num  1.35 1.32 1.28 1.33 1.4 ...
 $ R730 : num  1.49 1.47 1.44 1.47 1.52 ...
 $ R735 : num  1.61 1.59 1.58 1.59 1.61 ...
 $ R740 : num  1.7 1.68 1.68 1.68 1.68 ...
 $ R745 : num  1.77 1.74 1.75 1.75 1.72 ...
 $ R750 : num  1.81 1.79 1.8 1.79 1.75 ...
 $ R755 : num  1.84 1.82 1.83 1.82 1.77 ...
 $ R760 : num  1.85 1.83 1.85 1.84 1.78 ...
 $ R765 : num  1.86 1.84 1.86 1.85 1.79 ...
 $ R770 : num  1.87 1.85 1.86 1.85 1.79 ...
 $ R775 : num  1.87 1.85 1.87 1.85 1.8 ...
 $ R780 : num  1.87 1.85 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R785 : num  1.87 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R790 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R795 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R800 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R805 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R810 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R815 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.8 ...
 $ R820 : num  1.88 1.86 1.87 1.86 1.81 ...
 $ R825 : num  1.88 1.86 1.88 1.86 1.81 ...
 $ R830 : num  1.88 1.86 1.88 1.86 1.81 ...
 $ R835 : num  1.88 1.86 1.88 1.86 1.81 ...
 $ R840 : num  1.88 1.86 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R845 : num  1.88 1.86 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R850 : num  1.88 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R855 : num  1.88 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R860 : num  1.89 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R865 : num  1.89 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R870 : num  1.89 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R875 : num  1.89 1.87 1.88 1.87 1.81 ...
 $ R880 : num  1.89 1.87 1.89 1.87 1.82 ...
 $ R885 : num  1.89 1.87 1.89 1.87 1.82 ...
  [list output truncated]`
```

Comment: You need to provide the results of `str(logged)`.

Comment: It is as follows `> str(logged) 'data.frame': 100 obs. of 402 variables: $ R400 : num -1.92 -1.94 -1.93 -1.96 -2.05 ... `  The entire structure is too long to reproduce here.

Comment: The goal of the question was to find out whether 'y' was in logged and whether there were any columns that were factors or logical. Failing your willingness to provide information I guess you are on your own as far as investigation the collinearity. Searching SO for diagnosis singular matrices may be helpful.

Comment: All the columns are numerical.